# Choco forces a variable to true when it shouldn't

Tags: java, constraint-programming, choco

I am totally new to Choco and CP, but I am making a little model to solve the Steiner tree problem, and Choco keeps forcing the first node to be true whatever the graph is (and its not correct, I checked).

I have an array `es` of IntVar that ==1 if the edge is in the solution, or ==0 otherwise. Same for the array `vs` that sets vertices.
I use the array `activeEdgeW` to be able to have a scalar constraint where the coeffs are variable.
Then I just have the channeling constraints, the tree constraint and the sum == w constraint. And minimize w.  Fairly simple, but for some reason `vs[0] == true` always, for any graph.

My model is honestly pretty simple, I really don't know where that comes from:

```
    s = new Solver("Solver");
    vs = VF.boolArray("vs", nbV, s);
    es = VF.boolArray("es", nbE, s);
    w = VF.integer("w", 0, maxW, s);

    IntVar[] activeEdgeW = new IntVar[nbE];
    for(int i = 0; i < nbE; i++) { 
        activeEdgeW[i] = VF.enumerated("activeEdgeW["+i+"]", new int[]{0,ws[i]}, s); //Weight is either 0 or ws[i]
        ICF.arithm(activeEdgeW[i], "=", ws[i]).reifyWith(es[i]); //weight of edge is ws[i] if edge is in, 0 otherwise
    }


    UndirectedGraph UB = new UndirectedGraph(s, nbV, SetType.BITSET, false);
    UndirectedGraph LB = new UndirectedGraph(s, nbV, SetType.BITSET, false);

    //Building upper bound graph: has all nodes and edges
    for (int i = 0; i < nbV; i++){
        UB.addNode(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nbE; i++){
        UB.addEdge(endnodes[i][0], endnodes[i][1]);
    }

    //Building lower bound graph. Must contain Steiner nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < nbT; i++) {
        LB.addNode(terminals[i]);
    }



    g = GraphVarFactory.undirected_graph_var("Solution", LB, UB, s);
    s.post(GCF.tree(g));
    s.post(ICF.sum(activeEdgeW, w));

    s.post(GCF.nodes_channeling(g, vs));
    for (int i = 0; i < nbE; i++) {
        s.post(GCF.edge_channeling(g, es[i], endnodes[i][0], endnodes[i][1]));
    }


    s.plugMonitor((IMonitorSolution) () -> output());

    s.findOptimalSolution(ResolutionPolicy.MINIMIZE, w);
```

That's my model, the rest of the program is just the graph data.

Does any one have any clue of where this is coming? I tried putting the nodes in different orders in `UB`, but always the first node insists in being in.
I tried to remove the channeling constraint, and it showed me that the node is not always true, but an edge reaching it must be, so it becomes true. Nevertheless, as you can easily see, I have no constraints on the array `es` that would force an edge to be true whatsoever.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Choco3 I was using had a bug. It was solved in 3.3.0. Please use that one if you have the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

> "I am totally new to Choco and CP"

In the past I've been caught by tools that either did or did not beginning counting at zero and I assumed the opposite case (count starts at one).  The behavior you're describing falls within this category of bug so you might verify that all this starts with zero-based arrays.